# Are three legged tokens supported in the Autodisk BIM360 Account Admin endpoints?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I have tried the endpoints to get projects and users with a three legged token, and in both cases I get a 403 with a response body that looks like:

{
"code": 1003,
"message": "Only support 2 legged access token."
}

This seems unequivocal, but doesn't seem to be consistent with the API documentation. Is access really only available using a 2 legged token or have I missed something?

Just to be clear, the endpoints I'm playing with are:

```
GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/:account_id/projects 
and
GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/:account_id/users
```

The documentation states "Must be Bearer , where  is obtained via OAuth", but there is no mention that only two legged authentication tokens are supported.

Comment: It sounds that you're playing with [POST projects](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-POST/) and [POST projects/:project_id/users](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-POST/) of the BIM360 HQ API. If yes, it only supports 2 legged token currently. However, you can obtain projects from [GET hubs/:hub_id/projects](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-hub_id-projects-GET/) of the Forge Data Management API with 3 legged token.

Comment: Hi Eason, I've edited the question to provide more info. It is the GET endpoints I am referring to. The Data Management API alternative gives me what I want for projects, but not for users. Just want to make sure I haven't missed something before implementing a solution with two legged authentication, which seems less secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are BIM360 HQ APIs (well known as Account Admin APIs), part of [BIM360 API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/overview/introduction/) as I mentioned in the comment above.

Unfortunately, Account Admin APIs only allow access with 2 legged access token now. In contrast, other APIs like Issues, RFIs, and Checklists support 3 legged access token and 3 legged access token with the uid.

Note:

1. Keyword `user context required` in the Authentication Context of the documentation means that it requires acting with a [3-legged OAuth token](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/) or a [2-legged OAuth token with user impersonation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-2-legged-token/).
2. Keyword `app only` means that it supports [2-legged OAuth token](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/http/get-2-legged-token) only.